# Array Loop Writing Over Elements C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am writing to an array from a loop within a loop. The values are writing over themselves.

A couple of background notes, `keyname = GET_STRING_VALUE(Ds, Os, Fs, Rs, Is);` is pulling string values from a database. An example would be `71001093`. Those keys will be different for each Rs (record number for this database). The `Fk` and `Fs` relate to different columns in that database. The code is supposed to loop through (first 5) the records of the database and find the name relating it to a key. For the names that match keycmp, add them to the array.

#### The Issue

The ArrayCheck print outs at the bottom all display the last key entered into the array. The key & counter print out display the correct iterative number and associated key within the loop.

#### Code

```
char* status_keys [ 2 ][ 200 ];
int Ds, Os, Fs, Rs, Is, Fk, a, c;
char* keyname;
char* keycmp;
char* stationlookup[4];
char* key;

keycmp = "STRING";
for ( Rs = 1; Rs < 5; Rs++ ) {

    keyname = GET_STRING_VALUE(Ds, Os, Fs, Rs, Is);

    printf("keyname: %s\n", keyname);

do {
        strncpy(stationlookup, keyname, 4);
        stationlookup[4] = '\0';

        key = GET_STRING_VALUE(Ds, Os, Fk, Rs, Is);
        printf("key : %s\n",key);
        printf("counter : %d\n",a);


        status_keys[0][a] = key;
        status_keys[1][a] = stationlookup;

        a++;

    } while (strstr(keyname,keycmp) != NULL);

}

printf("ArrayCheck 0: %s\n", status_keys[0][0]);
printf("ArrayCheck 1: %s\n", status_keys[0][1]);
printf("ArrayCheck 2: %s\n", status_keys[0][2]);    
printf("ArrayCheck 3: %s\n", status_keys[0][3]);
```

Example Output:
[image]

Appreciate the `stationlookup` help, but this code still provides the writing over issue.

```
for ( Rs = 1; Rs < 5 ; Rs++ ) {

keyname = GET_STRING_VALUE(Ds, Os, Fs, Rs, Is);

printf("keyname: %s\n", keyname);

do {
        status_keys[0][a] = GET_STRING_VALUE(Ds, Os, Fk, Rs, Is);
        printf("key : %s\n",status_keys[0][a]);
        printf("counter : %d\n",a);
        a++;

    } while (strstr(keyname,keycmp) != NULL);

}
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample run/output? I'm not sure what the problem is. I do know that you likely mean to use `strlcpy` instead of `strncpy`. Also, you seem to be doing a "shallow copy" rather than a "deep copy" when assigning `status_keys[0][a] = key;` and `status_keys[1][a] = stationlookup;`.

Comment: Pointer issue maybe?  Try setting status_keys[0][a] to the GET_STRING_VALUE directly to avoid using the key variable.  This will at least tell you if there is a pointer issue with key.

Comment: Flyingcows00 - same issue with `status_keys[0][a] = GET_STRING_VALUE(Ds, Os, Fk, Rs, Is);`

Comment: regarding this line: char* stationlookup[4];  It is defining 4 pointers to strings, not an array of 4 characters.

Comment: regarding this line: stationlookup[4] = '\0';  It is writing into the 5th character pointer, however there are only 4 character pointers in the array of char pointers: stationlookup

Comment: regarding this line: strncpy(stationlookup, keyname, 4);  it is copying 4 characters into the array of char pointers: stationlookup.  Each pointer is (on a 32 bit system) 4 bytes, so your setting the stationlookup[0] to the contents of keyname.  Then setting the first byte of stationlookup[1] to '\0'.  Suggest changing 'char* stationlookup[4];' to 'char stationlookup[5];'

Comment: Your console output window indicates keyname is 6 characters, so you probably want to tweak your code to allow for all 6 characters + the terminator byte.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help with the `strncopy` and `stationlookup` issue, but i believe that is unrelated to the write-over i am experiencing here. Updated code with same error above

Comment: regarding this line: } while (strstr(keyname,keycmp) != NULL);, what you actually want to use is: } while (strcmp(keyname,keycmp) != 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problems come from these lines:

```
    status_keys[0][a] = key;
    status_keys[1][a] = stationlookup;
```

assuming that `GET_STRING_VALUE()` returns the same string pointer on each call. The above lines don't copy the strings but instead copy the string pointers which results in what looks like your array elements being overwritten. You can check this by printing the pointer value with:

```
   printf("keyptr : %p\n", key);
```

To correct this you'll need to change your code to something like:

```
   char status_keys [ 2 ][ 200 ][64];
   ...
   strncpy(status_keys[0][a], key, 62); // or strlcpy() if you have it
   strncpy(status_keys[1][a], stationlookup, 62);
```

or something like:

```
   char* status_keys [ 2 ][ 200 ];
   ...
   status_keys[0][a] = malloc(strlen(key)+1); 
   strcpy(status_keys[0][a], key);

      // Same for stationlookup
      // Make sure to free() the strings at some point
```

if you prefer dynamic memory access.

Comment: Thanks uesp, great explanation & examples.

Answer (score 3):

You declared:

```
char* stationlookup[4];
```

Which means that valid indicies are `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` and `[3]`.

So a line of code like this:

```
stationlookup[4] = '\0';
```

creates an array-overrun.

Comment: Nice catch, but if i completely remove the `stationlookup` and `strncpy` I still have the same issue.